# Multiple table conditional JOIN with excluded items

Tags: mysql, join, select

I'm creating an equipment hire tracking system that manages stock allocated to each job, this stock is also assigned to boxes.

I have the following tables:

Table boxes (list of containers, are assigned to job at fulfilment stage, job set to empty when returned)

```
box
job
...
```

Table codes (types of stock)

```
code
dept
type
description
...
```

Table jobs (jobs)

```
job
client
name
...
```

Table orders (orders related to a job)

```
id
job
...
```

Table orderitems (items related to an order)

```
id
order
code
quantity
...
```

Table fulfils (fulfilment of an orderitem, apply + quantity on ship, - quantity on return)

```
id
orderitem
code
quantity
...
```

Table stock (+ quantity on purchase, - quantity on disposal)

```
id
code
quantity
...
```

Table stockbox (apply + or - quantity of code to a box)

```
id
code
box
quantity
...
```

I've generated a result set that shows all fulfils for a job, when SUM(quantity) > 0 (to ignore returned items):

```sql
SELECT
    '' AS box,
    codes.code AS item,
    '' AS parent,
    codes.code AS code,
    codes.dept AS codedept,
    codes.type AS codestype,
    codes.description AS codedesc,
    '' AS make,
    '' AS model,
    '' AS name,
    '' AS serial,
    '' AS status,
    '' AS LOCATION,
    orders.job AS job,
    SUM(fulfils.quantity) AS quantity
FROM
    fulfils
    LEFT JOIN orderitems ON orderitems.id = fulfils.orderitem
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = orderitems.order
    LEFT JOIN codes ON codes.code = fulfils.code
WHERE
    orders.job = 'TEST'
GROUP BY
    fulfils.code,
    codes.dept,
    codes.type,
    codes.description,
    orders.job
HAVING
    quantity > 0;
```

This works as expected.

My challenge is now to separate this out into boxes based on their allocation to the job and their total stockbox allocation (SUM of stockbox quantities for that box and code). Also I need to include the fulfil total not allocated to any box (SUM of quantity - SUM of quantity assigned to a box). I'm ignoring the stock table for this purpose as not relevant, only stockbox.

Assuming box 'BOX01' is assigned to job 'TEST', 'BOX01' has a SUM of 3. Job 'TEST', code 'PRODUCT01' via table fulfils has a SUM of 5, I'm looking to see these results when running a query for .job = 'TEST'.

```
+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
|  box  |   item    | ... | quantity |
+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| BOX01 | PRODUCT01 | ... |        3 |
|       | PRODUCT01 | ... |        2 |
+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
```

I'm completely open to design changes. An easy workaround would be to add 'box' to fulfils, but I'd like the freedom to re-assign stock between boxes once stock has been fulfilled without affecting the fulfilment table.

Many thanks in advance.

Update:

This gets me somewhere near, creating lines for each box that is allocated to the job and the stock in it. I now need to subtract the SUM of the boxed quantities from the remaining fulfil quantity.

```sql
SELECT
    stockbox.box AS box,
    codes.code AS item,
    stockbox.box AS parent,
    codes.code AS code,
    codes.dept AS codedept,
    codes.type AS codestype,
    codes.description AS codedesc,
    '' AS make,
    '' AS model,
    '' AS name,
    '' AS serial,
    '' AS status,
    '' AS location,
    boxes.job AS job,
    SUM(stockbox.quantity) AS quantity
FROM
    stockbox
    LEFT JOIN codes ON codes.code = stockbox.code
    LEFT JOIN boxes ON boxes.box = stockbox.box
WHERE
    boxes.job = 'TEST'
GROUP BY
    stockbox.box,
    codes.code,
    codes.dept,
    codes.type,
    codes.description,
    boxes.box
HAVING
    quantity > 0
UNION
SELECT
    '' AS box,
    codes.code AS item,
    '' AS parent,
    codes.code AS code,
    codes.dept AS codedept,
    codes.type AS codestype,
    codes.description AS codedesc,
    '' AS make,
    '' AS model,
    '' AS name,
    '' AS serial,
    '' AS status,
    '' AS location,
    orders.job AS job,
    SUM(fulfils.quantity) AS quantity
FROM
    fulfils
    LEFT JOIN orderitems ON orderitems.id = fulfils.orderitem
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = orderitems.order
    LEFT JOIN codes ON codes.code = fulfils.code
WHERE
    orders.job = 'TEST'
GROUP BY
    fulfils.code,
    codes.dept,
    codes.type,
    codes.description,
    orders.job
HAVING
    quantity > 0;
```

Gives (remaining 5 should be 2):

```
+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
|  box  |   item    | ... | quantity |
+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
| BOX01 | PRODUCT01 | ... |        3 |
|       | PRODUCT01 | ... |        5 |
+-------+-----------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've cracked it:

```sql
SELECT
    stockbox.box AS box,
    codes.code AS item,
    stockbox.box AS parent,
    codes.code AS code,
    codes.dept AS codedept,
    codes.type AS codestype,
    codes.description AS codedesc,
    '' AS make,
    '' AS model,
    '' AS name,
    '' AS serial,
    '' AS status,
    '' AS LOCATION,
    boxes.job AS job,
    SUM(stockbox.quantity) AS quantity
FROM
    stockbox
    LEFT JOIN codes ON codes.code = stockbox.code
    LEFT JOIN boxes ON boxes.box = stockbox.box
WHERE
    boxes.job = 'TEST'
GROUP BY
    stockbox.box,
    codes.code,
    codes.dept,
    codes.type,
    codes.description,
    boxes.box
HAVING
    quantity > 0
UNION
SELECT
    '' AS box,
    codes.code AS item,
    '' AS parent,
    codes.code AS code,
    codes.dept AS codedept,
    codes.type AS codestype,
    codes.description AS codedesc,
    '' AS make,
    '' AS model,
    '' AS name,
    '' AS serial,
    '' AS status,
    '' AS LOCATION,
    orders.job AS job,
    SUM(fulfils.quantity) - (
        SELECT SUM(moo.quantity)
        FROM (
            SELECT
                stockbox.quantity AS quantity
            FROM
            stockbox
            LEFT JOIN boxes boxes2 ON boxes2.box = stockbox.box
            WHERE
                boxes2.job = 'TEST'
            ) AS moo
        ) AS quantity
FROM
    fulfils
    LEFT JOIN orderitems ON orderitems.id = fulfils.orderitem
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = orderitems.order
    LEFT JOIN codes ON codes.code = fulfils.code
WHERE
    orders.job = 'TEST'
GROUP BY
    fulfils.code,
    codes.dept,
    codes.type,
    codes.description,
    orders.job
HAVING
    quantity > 0;
```

It seems to achieve what I need, and given me a better understanding of summing nested selects.

Any other solutions greatly appreciated.